# Passing data with ajax to django with post method

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm try to send data to a django view through ajax with POST method as I saw in one tutorial.

The code I've made is the following (myURL is the URL where I call testview):

```
      $(document).on('submit','#form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'/myURL/',
          data:{
            HELLO: "I'm inside ajax data"
          },
          contentType: "application/json",
          datatype: 'json',
          sucess:function(){
            alert("Ajax pass data correctly");

          }
        })
      });
    </script>
```

And in django I'd call HELLO as following. test.html is where I have the html form

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

        takeHELLOfromajaxpost = request.POST['HELLO']

        return render(request,'test.html',{'dataTakenfromAjax':takeHELLOfromajaxpost})



    return render(request,'test.html',{})
```

Then I would template tagging in the same HTML {{ dataTakenfromAjax }} to verify if I'm taking that data , but nothing happens! I even get no error.

Comment: looks like a typo: `sucess` should be `success`. If this doesn't fix it, check the network tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not sending [`csrfmiddlewaretoken`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/) with your request.

Second, you have typo in `success` argument.

Third, you probably expecting it to completely change html? Than you should add `$("body").html()` at successful response. That way your variable appear on page.

test.html:

```
{{ dataTakenfromAjax }}

<form action="" id="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('submit', '#form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/myURL/',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
                HELLO: "I'm inside ajax data"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("body").html(data);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```